# QFileSystemModel crashing when seeting root path

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to learn how to display a `QFileSystemModel` as `TreeView` in QML, following this example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-example.html

I copied the non-main-function-code from the examples main.cpp into a header file, and try to use it in my main.cpp as follows:

```
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  qmlRegisterUncreatableType<DisplayFileSystemModel>("myfile", 1, 0,
                                                     "FileSystemModel", "Cannot create a FileSystemModel instance.");
  QFileSystemModel *fsm = new DisplayFileSystemModel(&engine);
  cout << "current path: "<< QDir::currentPath().toStdString() << endl;
  cout << "home path: "<< QDir::homePath().toStdString() << endl;
  //fsm->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
  fsm->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

However, I experience the following issue: If I do `fsm->setRootPath(QDir::homePath())` the app crashs on startup, if I use the `currentPath()` instead it is working fine. The output of the `cout` for the paths is fine for both. This happens regardless of whether I display anything in my qml files. What is the reason for the crash?

Edit: I realize now that the problem is related to the fact, that I am using a QGuiApplication. If I use a QApplication also homePath is working. Still, what is the reason for this behaviour, as the path is correctly retrieved in the `cout`?

Comment: Try instead: `fsm->setRootPath(QDir(QDir::homePath()).absolutePath());` and if still fails then verify with the log line if that path gets translated to absolute correctly.

Comment: Yes, this also fails, but gets translated correctly

Comment: You need to provide the crash stack and the debug output. Use debugger.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that QFileSystemModel requires a  QApplication to run.. it says so in the detailed description.

> Note: QFileSystemModel requires an instance of QApplication.

The other reason that it could fail is because QFileSystemModel creates a QFileSystemWatcher for each directory in the tree. QFileSystemWatcher can only have a maximum of so many instances on your machine under certain operating systems. This is due to RAM limitations as well as open file descriptor limits.   Every operating system is different, but if you have more files than your machine is able to watch concurrently, it will crash.

Specifically from the Documentation:

> On systems running a Linux kernel without inotify support, file
>   systems that contain watched paths cannot be unmounted. The act of
>   monitoring files and directories for modifications consumes system
>   resources. This implies there is a limit to the number of files and
>   directories your process can monitor simultaneously. On all BSD
>   variants, for example, an open file descriptor is required for each
>   monitored file. Some system limits the number of open file descriptors
>   to 256 by default. This means that addPath() and addPaths() will fail
>   if your process tries to add more than 256 files or directories to the
>   file system monitor. Also note that your process may have other file
>   descriptors open in addition to the ones for files being monitored,
>   and these other open descriptors also count in the total. macOS uses a
>   different backend and does not suffer from this issue.